# jquery placeholder text for input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, placeholder

I'm using jquery placeholder text for a search placeholder. This search field doesn't have any placeholder so i added this text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.mfilter-search').find("input[type=text]").each(function(ev)
     {
       if(!$(this).val()) {
       $(this).attr("placeholder", "Refine Your Search");
     }
   });
});
```

i don't know it's the best way to add a placeholder using jquery. If anyone know  more simple way please add your code it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly set the `placeholder` no need to check `value` and use `.each()`

```
$('.mfilter-search input[type=text]').attr("placeholder", "Refine Your Search")
```

If you want to place on first then use

```
$('.mfilter-search input[type=text]:first').attr("placeholder", "Refine Your Search")
```

Comment: if there is two text field and i just want to put my placeholder only one and both text field has same class then?

Comment: @shamimkhan, How will you identify in which text field you need to set placeholder, I means whats the criteria?

Comment: there is two input field and i need to add placeholder for the first input field

Comment: @shamimkhan, Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `find` method using `value` attribute

```
$('.mfilter-search').find("input[type=text][!value]").attr("placeholder", "Refine Your Search");
```

Comment: so this value will set if there is no placeholder already set right

Comment: If it is already set it will replace the value of placeholder

Answer (score 1):

you can add placeholder attribute directly in your html element like this

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="search">
```

or you can add a class to all your element that you need to put placeholder eg:- `.placeholder` and add placeholder attribute in javascript like this.

```
$(".placeholder").attr("placeholder", "Type here to search");
```

or you can use plugins like these.
http://andrewrjones.github.io/jquery-placeholder-plugin/ or
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder or refer this site  for different placeholder plugins.
https://www.sitepoint.com/top-5-jquery-html5-placeholder-plugins/

and your code is also good. We can do that way too.
hope this will work.

Comment: i think this is a bad idea to use plugin only for placeholder

Comment: it will reduce the complexity of code. and it will not harm more because it is just a simple code snippet. if you want to use it use it . or try jquery methods.

Comment: if you dont want to use plugins then the best way is to ad class to element and put placeholder attribute for that class

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.mfilter-search').find("input[type=text]").each(function(ev)
     {
           var txt = $(this).data('placeholder');
            $(this).attr('placeholder', txt);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For place holder no need complex method function in jquery simply use like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder = "Zipcode" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Zipcode'" name="zipcode" class="form-control" maxlength='10'>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. this is how you can add `place holder` if you have two `input fields` with same `class name`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<body>

first name :<input type="text" name="firstname" class="tfield" id="field0">
last name :<input type="text" name="lastname" class="tfield" id="field1">

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 var thelength = $(".tfield").length;
 for(var i=0;i<thelength;i++)
 {
  var theid = $("#field"+i);
  var thename = theid.attr("name");
  alert(thename);
  
  if(thename == "firstname")
  {
   theid.attr("placeholder","name");
  }

 }
});


</script>

</html>
```